# Invalid JSON response jquery datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables

I create c# web method to retrieve data from database and call this web method with ajax request to show it in data-table.

js code:

```
var TableEditable = function () {

var handleTable = function () {

    function restoreRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

        for (var i = 0, iLen = jqTds.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            oTable.fnUpdate(aData[i], nRow, i, false);
        }

        oTable.fnDraw();
    }

    function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
        jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
        jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
        jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
        jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';
        jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';
        jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="">Cancel</a>';
    }

    function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 4, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>', nRow, 5, false);
        oTable.fnDraw();
    }

    function cancelEditRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 4, false);
        oTable.fnDraw();
    }

    var table = $('#sample_editable_1');

    var oTable = table.dataTable({



        // Uncomment below line("dom" parameter) to fix the dropdown overflow issue in the datatable cells. The default datatable layout
        // setup uses scrollable div(table-scrollable) with overflow:auto to enable vertical scroll(see: assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js). 
        // So when dropdowns used the scrollable div should be removed. 
        //"dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",

        "lengthMenu": [
            [5, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
        ],

        // Or you can use remote translation file
        //"language": {
        //   url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Portuguese.json'
        //},

        // set the initial value
        "pageLength": 10,

        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": " _MENU_ records"
        },
        "columnDefs": [{ // set default column settings
            'orderable': true,
            'targets': [0]
        }, {
            "searchable": true,
            "targets": [0]
        }],
        "ajax": {
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "iDisplayStart": 0,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/WS/WS.asmx/GetCustomers",
            "sServerMethod": "GET",
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",

            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        },
        "order": [
            [0, "asc"]
        ] // set first column as a default sort by asc
    });

    var tableWrapper = $("#sample_editable_1_wrapper");

    tableWrapper.find(".dataTables_length select").select2({
        showSearchInput: true //hide search box with special css class
    }); // initialize select2 dropdown

    var nEditing = null;
    var nNew = false;

    $('#sample_editable_1_new').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (nNew && nEditing) {
            if (confirm("Previose row not saved. Do you want to save it ?")) {
                saveRow(oTable, nEditing); // save
                $(nEditing).find("td:first").html("Untitled");
                nEditing = null;
                nNew = false;

            } else {
                oTable.fnDeleteRow(nEditing); // cancel
                nEditing = null;
                nNew = false;

                return;
            }
        }

        var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData(['', '', '', '', '', '']);
        var nRow = oTable.fnGetNodes(aiNew[0]);
        editRow(oTable, nRow);
        nEditing = nRow;
        nNew = true;
    });

    table.on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this row ?") == false) {
            return;
        }

        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
        alert("Deleted! Do not forget to do some ajax to sync with backend :)");
    });

    table.on('click', '.cancel', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (nNew) {
            oTable.fnDeleteRow(nEditing);
            nEditing = null;
            nNew = false;
        } else {
            restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
            nEditing = null;
        }
    });

    table.on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        /* Get the row as a parent of the link that was clicked on */
        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

        if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {
            /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
            restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
            editRow(oTable, nRow);
            nEditing = nRow;
        } else if (nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == "Save") {
            /* Editing this row and want to save it */
            saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
            nEditing = null;
            alert("Updated! Do not forget to do some ajax to sync with backend :)");
        } else {
            /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
            editRow(oTable, nRow);
            nEditing = nRow;
        }
    });
}

return {

    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {
        handleTable();
    }

  };

}();
```

C# web Method :

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetCustomers()
{

    DataTable dt = ICMS_DB_CLS.GetDataFromDB("Select * from  t_crm_customers");
    List<Customers> lis = new List<Customers>();

    lis = ExtensionList.ToListof<Customers>(dt);
    var d= new { sEcho = 1,
        iTotalRecords =20,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = 20,
        aaData = lis };



    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, Formatting.Indented);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = -1;
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);

}
```

My Error:

> Invalid JSON response jquery datatable

and my json response is that :

```
{"data": [
  {
    "CustomerId": 2,
    "CustomerType": "type      ",
    "CustomerCode": "123",
    "CustomerName": "salah sayed",
    "CustomerAddress": "Mohammed kamel hussien",
    "CustomerEmail": "salah.rzzaz90@gmail.com",
    "CustomerTel1": "0226248850",
    "CustomerTel2": "0226248851",
    "CustomerMobile": "01067395199",
    "CustFirstBal": 1.00,
    "LimitMony": 20.00,
    "FlagAccType": "a",
    "CustomerDisc": 3.00
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option should be:

```js
// ... skipped ...
"ajax": {
    url: "/WS/WS.asmx/GetCustomers",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
},
// ... skipped ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON Object must be like this

```
        {
            sEcho = <integer sent to server>,
            iTotalRecords = <All  Records Count>,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = <All  Records Count>,
            aaData = <you list of data>,                
        }
```

Version 1.11

Comment: {
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": 20,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 20,
  "aaData": [
    {
      "CustomerId": 2,
      "CustomerType": "type      ",
      "CustomerCode": "123",
      "CustomerName": "salah sayed",
      "CustomerAddress": "Mohammed kamel hussien",
      "CustomerEmail": "salah.rzzaz90@gmail.com",
      "CustomerTel1": "0226248850",
      "CustomerTel2": "0226248851",
      "CustomerMobile": "01067395199",
      "CustFirstBal": 1.00,
      "LimitMony": 20.00,
      "FlagAccType": "a",
      "CustomerDisc": 3.00
    }
  ]
}             Not working

Comment: @salah your JSOn is valid. if you just say `not working`, how can people answer ?post the  error also

Comment: try this , remove all lines of `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.*` just use `return json;` and in method definition replace `void` with `string`

Comment: <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":20,"iTotalDisplayRecords":20,"aaData":[{"CustomerId":2,"CustomerType":"type ","CustomerCode":"123","CustomerName":"salah sayed","CustomerAddress":"Mohammed kamel hussien","CustomerEmail":"salah.rzzaz90@gmail.com","CustomerTel1":"0226248850","CustomerTel2":"0226248851","CustomerMobile":"01067395199","CustFirstBal":1.00,"LimitMony":20.00,"FlagAccType":"a","CustomerDisc":3.00}]}
</string>

Comment: last 2 options i got are 1. which version of datatablea are you using ? 2.  use this line `"success": function (data) {console.log(data)}` in ajax options and   and say what you can see in console

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was because I wasn't declaring the ajax method call type.

See my code on ajax call, maybe It helps you.

```
$('#ajax-table').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "../admin/AjaxListarEmpresas",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
```